# which server side language nginx webserver supports

Tags: nginx, webserver, proxy-server

which server side language nginx webserver do support? For example apachi-tomcat is for java, wammp is for php. and secondly it is installed on my pc i need to know that how can i access it via http and in which do i need to put my applications

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No language. It is primarily designed as a static and front-end proxy server.

The server itself is written in C and supports C-compatible plug-ins, but the plug-in architecture is heavily geared towards interfacing with other servers on the back end, not to add, e.g., PHP support.

Comment: Ok. then how can we use it in best possible way as a web server

Comment: @AliRaza: I don't understand your question. I've explained the normal use of nginx. Are you after something more?

Answer (score 5):

WAMP is not a webserver. **W**indows **A**pache **M**ySQL **P**HP. 
Usually web-server do not came with language support. They either have modules, for apache it's like mod_php, mod_python, mod_passenger, etc, for nginx there's no module, you'll need standalone fastCGI or PHP-FPM.

So basically nginx can support any language with fastCGI or fastCGI-like interface available.